# How to extract .ipa (Binary) for HP Fortify on demand

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am just confused on which type of provisioning profile I should use for submission of the Binary file on HP Fortify on demand.

Comment: you want to extract the .ipa or you want to submit the ipa ?

Comment: Extract .ipa for Submission.